# Yii WHERE IN with multiple where

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id
listingId
type
distance
```

Where listingId is a foreign key to a table of listings, type is a handle for type of place, and distance is just an integer. And I want to be able to get all listingIds that fulfil a set of 1-5 queries. This is what I have so far:

```
$records = MyActiveRecord::find()
            ->select('listingId')
            ->where(['and', 'type="hospital"', "distance <= 130"])
            ->orWhere(['and', 'type="airport"', 'distance <= 600'])
            ->all();
```

Now this will return all hits as expected, but what I'm after are just the listingIds that show up twice (in this scenario, if there are three `WHERE` clauses I would want the ones that have 3 hits, and so on).

I'm guessing I would have to go for a `WHERE IN`, but I'm not sure how to do that with a subquery?

Any suggestions? Thanks.

**EDIT (specifying a bit)**

So what I'm after is any listingIds that have *both* hospital *and* airport within the given distances. The query given above gives me any listingId where it's *either* of them. And in that case wherever there are two identical `listingId` it would mean that I have a match on both, and that's the `listingId` I want.

Comment: use where with IN condition to select types and then check the distance with another andWhere

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the way to do it with SQL, so in the end I just used `findBySql` and wrote out my query:

```
$distances = [ // will come from query
    [
        'type' => 'hospital',
        'distance' => 130
    ],
    [
        'type' => 'airport',
        'distance' => 600
    ]
];

$query = 'select listingId from myTable
      where type = "' . $distances[0]['type'] . '"
      and distance <= ' . $distances[0]['distance'];

foreach(array_slice($distances, 1) as $dist) {
    $query = 'select listingId from myTable
        where type = "' . $dist['type'] . '"
        and distance <= ' . $dist['distance'] . '
        and listingId in (' . $query . ')';
}
```

Which ends up looking something like this

```
select listingId from myTable
where type = 'bar'
and distance <= 130
and listingId in (
  select listingId from myTable
  where type = 'airport'
  and distance <= 600
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$subQuery = MyActiveRecord::find()->select('listingId')->where(['and',['type' => 'airport'],['<=', 'distance', 600]]);
$records = MyActiveRecord::find()
                        ->select('listingId')
                        ->where(['and', ['type' => 'hospital'], ['<=', 'distance', 130]])
                        ->orWhere(['in', 'listingId', $subQuery])
                        ->all();
```

Comment: Just letting you know that I'm not the one that downvoted you, but I was looking at a solution like this. The problem is that it will create a new query for each subquery. And since it might go up to 5, and in some cases even higher, that's not really ideal.